# Django Beautiful Soup Changing User Agent - No Effect

Tags: django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to run a webscraping application. However, this code is only working for some sites even though I set the user agent (have tried several different ones). This code does work on my dev site (which is hosted on a subdomain of pythonanywhere), but not on my production site. So it seems as if I am blocked from certain sites (even though I have not been accessing them very much at all if ever). Any ideas? Could I simply email the websites and see if I can be granted access as I am not doing anything malicious.

```
url = request.GET['url']
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    if not soup.find('meta', property="og:title"):
        title = soup.title.string
    else:
        title = soup.find('meta', property="og:title")['content']

    if "403" in title or not title:
        import urllib2
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        response = opener.open(url)
        page = response.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

        if not soup.find('meta', property="og:title"):
            title = soup.title.string
        else:
            title = soup.find('meta', property="og:title")['content']
```

Comment: What response code are you getting from the sites that fail? (You will need to catch the `urllib2.HTTPError` exception to determine this.

Comment: You might also consider using the [requests[(http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library which is much easier to work with than urllib2.

Comment: if you are somehow a paying user for your dev account but a free user for your production account, then pythonanywhere may be restricting outgoing internet access for your production account to only whitelisted sites